# How do I calculate the cost of Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I need to calculate the cost of the Azure Synapse Analytics. I have used the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) but I could not figure it out. It shows close to USD 2,100.

[image]

I have the following components as a part of the Azure Synapse Analytics

1. Synapse workspace
2. Self Hosted agent - Standard_B2s
3. Synapse SQL pool

How do I calculate the cost of Azure Synapse Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [sample pricing calculator](https://azure.com/e/a934a5385fe44ecfadbcae67905f9692) filled out to describe your situation. The assumptions are below.

- you are using a Dedicated SQL pool not a Serverless SQL pool
- you have scaled the dedicated SQL pool to DWU100c and left it running 24 hours a day (if you programmatically pause it then that would reduce the cost)
- you do not want to commit to running it 24 hours a day for 1 or 3 years and get reserved pricing discounts
- in the dedicated SQL pool you have under 1TB of data (compressed) and you have geo-redundant backups enabled
- you are running under 1,000 pipeline activities per month on the self-hosted integration runtime, copy activities run less than an hour per month, and other activity hours are less than 7 hours per month.
- you are not using other parts of Synapse like Spark pools, data flows, Data Explorer pools, Synapse Serverless SQL, etc.
- you are in the East US Azure region
- you have a B2s virtual machine with a 128GB premium SSD OS disk and no other attached disks where the self-hosted IR is installed. It is running 24 hours a day. (The VM cost but not storage cost could be lowered if you pause and resume it programmatically)
- on the B2s virtual machine you do not want to commit to running it 24 hours a day for 1 or 3 years to get a reserved pricing discount and you are renting the Windows license with the VM rather than bringing your license with Azure Hybrid Benefit
- this is retail pricing

Comment: That's a good insight on the pricing. I'm looking for the same Azure synapse analytics cost estimation which involves Azure Storage, Azure data pipeline and Spark pool. All with minimal configuration. Will you be able to give the estimate?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult question to answer, because most of the costs are consumption/runtime oriented.

The pricing calculator defaults are not great, so you'll really want to fine tune it. For instance, you cannot remove Dedicated Pools, but you can set the Hours to 0. It also includes Data Explorer, which cannot be removed. To not include these prices in the calculator, deselect the "Auto select engine instances", and under both Engine V-Cores and Data Management V-Cores, set the hours to 0.

The calculator will NOT include any time for Spark pools (Notebooks) or Data Flows. These are both heavily consumption oriented which will vary greatly based on your runtime choices like pool size. Their costs are based on minutes of consumption, so good luck predicting that.